# Does "readonly" in "FetchTask.php" when "main.php" contains several "$urls" in my case will not cause error?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use this `amphp/parallel` PHP Package (https://github.com/amphp/parallel) But I'm facing a serious problem.

I have a blocking function named `getDetails` that gets contents from different urls.

**So, here is my `main.php` code:**

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Amp\Future;
use Amp\Parallel\Worker;
use function Amp\async;

$urls = [
    'https://website1.net',
    'https://website2.org',
    'https://website3.com',
];

$executions = [];
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    // FetchTask is just an example, you'll have to implement
    // the Task interface for your task.
    $executions[$url] = Worker\submit(new FetchTask($url));
}

// Each submission returns an Execution instance to allow two-way
// communication with a task. Here we're only interested in the
// task result, so we use the Future from Execution::getFuture()
$responses = Future\await(array_map(
    fn (Worker\Execution $e) => $e->getFuture(),
    $executions,
));

foreach ($responses as $url => $response) {
    \printf("Read %d bytes from %s\n", \strlen($response), $url);
}
```

**When that `FetchTask.php` file should contain:**

```
use Amp\Cancellation;
use Amp\Parallel\Worker\Task;
use Amp\Sync\Channel;

class FetchTask implements Task
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly string $url,
    ) {
    }

    public function run(Channel $channel, Cancellation $cancellation): string
    {
        return getDetails($this->url); // Example blocking function
    }
}
```

Does that `FetchTask` should normally content `readonly` in its controller knowing that `main.php` contains several `$urls` ???

**Do I need to use `readonly` in `FetchTask.php` when `main.php` contains several `$urls` in my case knowing that `readonly` (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.properties.php) prevents property modification after initialization and `$url` should be modified everytime in `getDetails($this->url)` ???**

What could be correct `FetchTask.php` content in case `main.php` contains several `$urls` knowing that I use `readonly` ???

Thanks to answer me.

Comment: main.php, has several URLs, but each is being assigned to a dedicated new instance of your task, so I’m not seeing any problems

Comment: All right. Thanks.